# Oracle query alphabet replacement

Tags: sql, oracle, replace

I want to print the FIRST_NAME from Intern table after replacing ‘a’ with ‘A’.
The table is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE INTERN
(
    INTERN_ID NUMBER,
    FIRST_NAME VARCHAR2 (20),
    LAST_NAME VARCHAR2 (20),
    SALARY NUMBER,
    JOINING_DATE DATE,
    DEPARTMENT VARCHAR2 (20)
);

INSERT INTO INTERN VALUES (001, 'Monika', 'Arora', 100000, TO_DATE('2014-02-20 09:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 'HR');
INSERT INTO INTERN VALUES (002, 'Niharika', 'Verma', 80000, TO_DATE('2014-06-11 09:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 'Admin');
INSERT INTO INTERN VALUES (003, 'Vishal', 'Singhal', 300000, TO_DATE('2014-02-20 09:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 'HR');
INSERT INTO INTERN VALUES (004, 'Amitabh', 'Singh', 500000, TO_DATE('2014-02-20 09:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 'Admin');
INSERT INTO INTERN VALUES (005, 'Vivek', 'Bhati', 500000, TO_DATE('2014-06-11 09:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 'Admin');
INSERT INTO INTERN VALUES (006, 'Vipul', 'Diwan', 200000, TO_DATE('2014-06-11 09:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 'Account');
INSERT INTO INTERN VALUES (007, 'Satish', 'Kumar', 75000, TO_DATE('2014-01-20 09:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 'Account');
INSERT INTO INTERN VALUES (008, 'Geetika', 'Chauhan', 90000, TO_DATE('2014-04-11 09:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 'Admin');
```

I tried with this query:

```
SELECT REPLACE (FIRST_NAME, "a", "A") FROM INTERN;
```

getting "%s: invalid identifier" with this query.

Requesting help.

Thanks!

Comment: It is a **single quote**, not double.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried changing " to ' ?

It is look like

```
SELECT REPLACE (FIRST_NAME, 'a', 'A') FROM INTERN;
```